# Dart unit testing classes in a html-dependant library

Tags: unit-testing, dart

I have a library which uses `CanvasElement` and therefor is dependent on `dart:html`. Now I'm trying to write unit-tests for that same library. However, I get the following error when trying to run them:

```
The built-in library 'dart:html' is not available on the stand-alone VM.
```

Here is how my test file looks like:

```dart
library PiflexUmlTest;

import 'package:PiflexUml/lib.dart';
import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';

part 'src/geometry/vector_test.dart';

main () {
  testVector();
}
```

I understand it's failing because library itself in `lib.dart` file has a line stating:

```dart
library PiflexUml;
// ....
import 'dart:html';

part "blahblah.dart";
part "something_else.dart"
// ....
```

Even though library itself is dependent on it, I'm not trying to test a class which has anything to do with HTML.

What are my solutions here? Is there a way to just import classes I want to test without importing the whole lib? Or do I have to split my lib into html-dependent part and non-html-dependent part?

Answer (score 5):

You could run browser based unit tests with `content_shell` (headless browser).

The folder where you installed DartEditor to (darteditor/chromium/download_contentshell.sh) contains a script file to download the part containing `content_shell`.

You need an HTML file that is run by `content_shell` and that runs the tests. The HTML file could look like

```dart
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
  <script src="packages/unittest/test_controller.js"></script>
  <script type="application/dart" src="browser_tests.dart"></script> <!-- your unit tests -->
  <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>      </body>
</html>
```

**Dart unit tests**

```dart
import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';
import 'package:unittest/html_config.dart';

main() {
  useHtmlConfiguration();

  test('test scope', () {
    ...
  });
}
```

Maybe overkill for your use case, but still a solution.

**EDIT**
There is also a discussion going on about this problem: 
https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/pacB66gnVcg

Comment: content_shell and polymer.dart throw exception for me about CORS resctricion "Imported resource from origin 'file://' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy"

Comment: sorry, i am forget --allow-file-access-from-files

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be fixed in newer versions of the test package.  There is a new parameter '--platform' that accepts a browser as a value so:

```
pub run test --platform chrome
```

Will compile your tests to javascript and run them on chrome.

You can also use the @TestOn annotation, or the testOn parameter to test() or group() to specify 'vm' or 'browser' if you're writing a library that should work in both locations.

See https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/test#browservm-hybrid-tests